# What type of SMD LED packages are used in the for tell tale in the dashboard of bikes?

Tags: led, indicator

I am trying to identify what kind of LEDs are used in tell tales found in the dashboards of bikes etc. The ones used to show if the high beam, indicator is turned on or any warning lights.

Because the more I look into LED packages, I am unable to find a common package that can have multiple colors and also have similar peak intensity.

Edit based on Mod's comment:
I am currently using PLCC2 as the package which I thought was the one that is fit for the application. I need at least 1cd as the luminous intensity.The problem here is that for ex, for color blue - the brightest part has an intensity of 600mcd. This means all other color LEDs must also be current limited to give out 600mcd so they all look uniform. This is the dilemma.

Comment: You can always change the intensity of an LED by changing the current you drive it with. Lower current = lower brightness, and it's approximately linear.

Comment: You don't want to run the LED at it's peak brightness unless the goal is to annoy or blind the user. Typically indictor lights are run at a few percent of max, depending on circumstances.

Comment: Abhijith - Hi, Your question: "*Anyone here who has worked on similar projects?*" is not a good fit for this site, as it invites a discussion after someone answers "yes". Instead, please edit your question to ask a clear [on-topic](/help/on-topic) *technical* question. For example, are you asking how to make different colour LEDs have a similar perceived brightness to human vision (which is colour-dependent)? Also you should explain exactly what you have tried so far (specifically - share your research), what results you got, exactly where you are stuck, and what help you need. Thanks.

Comment: @Hearth The problem is in the package PLCC2 (which I choose thinking was the common package used for these application) the color blue has a max brightness of only 600mcd. There are no manufacturers that makes Blue LEDs in PLCC2 package with brightness more that 600mcd and I need at least 1000mcd.

That's where this post is coming from.

Comment: @Abhijith 1000 mcd seems extremely bright for an indicator light. I would think a tenth of that would be adequate.

Comment: @Hearth I have added my application below in another comment. For such an application, 1000mcd is still less.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard specification. however, [SMD packages are commonly used.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Instrument_panel_PCB.jpg) sometimes use a regular bulb socket, too.

A car's electrical system has very rough conditions. for use in these conditions, Most major LED manufacturers have product lineups that meet automotive grade ratings. Typically classified as an User inferface LED, but sometimes found in the [categories of Automotive HVAC](https://www.vishay.com/en/applications/automotive/hvac_climatecontrol/user_interface/leds/).

[image: If-Forward Current Figure]

brightness of the LED usually increases linearly with the current. it is usually marked with "[Luminous Intensity](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81219/vlmk2300.pdf)".

Comment: Yes, I have been using the same PLCC2 as the package with the LEDs from the same family by Vishay. But the brightness is too low. After populating these in my application I have realized that I need like 1cd or 1000mcd minimum for the lights to be visible under the sun.
I am unable to find the LEDs with all colours I want with almost 1cd brightness in the same PLCC2 package. That's basically why I was trying to know if maybe there was another package that is commonly used for the this application.

Comment: @Abhijith lamps used in the dashboard's warning lights are usually intended to illuminate relatively dark and narrow gaps and need not be too bright. (think about the brightness of a tiny light bulb of 12V that was used before LEDs became popular!) How is your application intended to be used under direct sunlight?

Comment: My application is for a dashboard of a bike. ([Like in this image here] (https://www.zabikers.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/166141_125_390-Duke-Dashboard-MY17-NIGHTMODE.jpg)) The engine light, High Beam indicator, Neutral Indicator etc. So this comes under direct sunlight.

Comment: @Abhijith Yes, then LEDs are a well-known things. You need some kind of mask to properly block or pass the light. it acts as a darkroom and helps to see the LED light well. or you can use a part called "Light pipe".